# Group records based on time interval starting from timestamp of first record in each group

Tags: sql-server

Struggling with this; need to group records within a specific time interval starting from the first timestamp (FREEZE_TIME) - but the first record outside the first group is the starting point for the time interval for the next group and so on. Expected result, THAW_COUNT, is the count of all groups for a PARENT_SAMPLE_ID. So for table:

| SAMPLE_ID | FREEZE_TIME | PARENT_SAMPLE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| 2 | 2015-11-27 10:23:10 | 1 |
| 3 | 2015-11-27 10:59:23 | 1 |
| 4 | 2015-11-27 11:05:43 | 1 |
| 5 | 2015-11-27 12:53:48 | 1 |
| 6 | 2015-11-27 13:42:25 | 1 |

I would like to get a result of:

| PARENT_SAMPLE_ID | THAW_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

So sample_id:s 2,3 and 4 should be in the same group and sample id:s 5 and 6 are in the next group.

I have tried something like:

```
with SampleList as
(
    select PARENT_SAMPLE_ID, FREEZE_TIME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by PARENT_SAMPLE_ID order by FREEZE_TIME asc) RN
    from    
        SAMPLE
)
,
FirstSample as
(
    select PARENT_SAMPLE_ID, FREEZE_TIME
    from SampleList
    where RN = 1
)
,
SelectedSample as
(
    select 
        s.PARENT_SAMPLE_ID, 
        ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, s.FREEZE_TIME, sFirst.FREEZE_TIME))/60 DiffToFirst 
    from SampleList s
    inner join FirstSample sFirst ON s.PARENT_SAMPLE_ID = sFirst.PARENT_SAMPLE_ID
    group by s.PARENT_SAMPLE_ID, ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, s.FREEZE_TIME, sFirst.FREEZE_TIME))/60
)

select PARENT_SAMPLE_ID, count(*) THAW_COUNT
from SelectedSample
group by PARENT_SAMPLE_ID
```

But this will return a THAW_COUNT of 3 as sampleId:s 5 and 6 will be in different groups because the grouping is based on hour intervals from freeze time of sampleId 2 only. How do I get the grouping for group 2 to start from the first record outside the first group (sampleId 5) and so on?

Answer (score 0):

This can be treated as a gaps and islands problem. Using some windows functions to check counts and using LAG to look at the "previous" row we can solve this. If you have multiple values for SAMPLE_ID you will want to add some partitioning.

```
create table #Something
(
    SAMPLE_ID int
    , FREEZE_TIME datetime
    , PARENT_SAMPLE_ID int
)
insert #Something
select 1, null, null union all
select 2, '2015-11-27 10:23:10', 1 union all
select 3, '2015-11-27 10:59:23', 1 union all
select 4, '2015-11-27 11:05:43', 1 union all
select 5, '2015-11-27 12:53:48', 1 union all
select 6, '2015-11-27 13:42:25', 1;

with MyGroups as
(
    select *
        , GroupNum = count(IsNewGroup) over (order by FREEZE_TIME rows unbounded preceding)
    from
    (
        select *
            , IsNewGroup = case when LAG(FREEZE_TIME, 1, '') over(order by FREEZE_TIME) < dateadd(hour, -1, FREEZE_TIME) then 1 end
        from #Something
    ) x
)

select coalesce(PARENT_SAMPLE_ID, SAMPLE_ID)
    , count(distinct GroupNum)
from MyGroups
group by coalesce(PARENT_SAMPLE_ID, SAMPLE_ID)

drop table #Something
```